# how to match value from Excel with database?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, count, controller

I have an Excel file and will upload and save to database.

In the Excel file, there are several columns, for example:

```
No    IC  Amount
1     123  800
2     124  900
3     125  890
```

...and in table in the database:

No IC Amount

```
1  123  0
2  124  0
```

It's only updating the field when IC field matched between Excel and database.

What i want to ask how to count mathed and unmatched IC? I want to give notification such as:

> **number of data successfully to update**

or

> **number of IC not matched with database**

This is my PHP code:

```
$numbers = Loandisburse::where('ic', $value['ic_no'])->count();
```

Comment: Cleaned it up, but I think the OP needs to provide a lot more PHP code, because this question in unsalvagable at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Declare two variables and set their default value to 0 ($match,$unmatch). Then when you go through the for loop for checking the IC value, if the IC values matches then do matches++ and if doesn't match then do unmatches++. In this way, you can get the number of matched and unmatched value once the for loop ends.